Setting the order of bundled scripts in WebOptimizer
I am using WebOptimizer in an ASP.NET Core app with pretty standard config like
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
    {
        pipeline.MinifyJsFiles("js/a.js", "js/b.js", "js/c.js");
    });
}

My question is, how can I control the order of the scripts in the bundled and minified files? It appears the order in the config is ignored and I am unable to really work out how it does order them. Alpha order also seems to change nothing.
